# What is the type of immutable object in Python (for mypy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I always use `mypy` in my **Python** programs.

What is the type (from `typing`) for immutable objects, the ones that could be used for a dictionary key?

To put back into context, I want to write a class inherited from dictionary and I have the following code

```
class SliceableDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, attr:Any) -> Any:
        return super().__getitem__(attr)
```

Type hints in that case are pretty useless, isn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The keys of a `dict` are [*hashable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) (see [the first sentence of the docs on `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)), and the hashable type is [`typing.Hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Hashable), an alias for [`collections.abc.Hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Hashable).

Comment: [Deprecated since version 3.12: Use collections.abc.Hashable directly instead.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Hashable)

Answer (score 6):

[`typing.Hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Hashable) refers to any type that can serve as a valid key in a `dict` or value in a `set`.

It doesn't *require* true immutability (any object can [define `__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)), but in general, hashable things should be things that are "treated as immutable", since it will break things should they be mutated after insertion into a `set` or after being inserted as a `dict` key.

Comment: Both your answer and jwodder's answer are great.. I have selected the other one just because I saw it first. Thanks again for the time spent enlightening me!

Comment: [Deprecated since version 3.12: Use collections.abc.Hashable directly instead.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Hashable)