# Is it possible to hint that a function parameter should not be modified?

Tags: python, type-hinting

For example, I might have an abstract base class with some abstract method that takes some mutable type as a parameter:

```py
from abc import *

class AbstractClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_method(self, mutable_parameter: list | set):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Is there some way of hinting to the function implementer that this parameter should not be modified in any implementation of this method?

I imagine maybe something like `ReadOnly` could exist:

```py
def abstract_method(self, mutable_parameter: ReadOnly[list]):
```

but I can't seem to find anything suggesting such a thing does exist.

From looking at the typing module docs I would have assumed that `Final` was what I am looking for but PyCharm tells me `'Final' could not be used in annotations for function parameters`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible because there is no reliable way for a static type checker to determine which methods of a mutable object would mutate the object and which methods would not in a generic fashion. Best to type hint the parameters as immutable objects such as tuples and frozensets in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the type of immutable object in Python (for mypy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564624/what-is-the-type-of-immutable-object-in-python-for-mypy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to find a structural superclass that provides the behaviors you want. There's a good summary of the available collections classes at [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), but as a quick, non-exhaustive summary.

- If you're just planning to iterate over the collection in some order, you're looking for [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable).
- If all you're doing is using the infix `in` operator to check for membership, you can use [`Container`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Container).
- [`Collection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection) is `Iterable` plus `Container` plus the `len` function.
- [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) gives you `Collection`, `__getitem__` (i.e. the square brackets operator), and several other nice list-y things. This is a good general-purpose candidate for list-like structures.

None of these protocols have any mutating methods, so if you adhere strictly to your types (and don't downcast), then you can be assured that a function taking these types will not mutate the argument.

Note that, prior to [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) (released in Python 3.9), the `collections.abc` classes were non-generic. If you need to be compatible with Python versions prior to that, the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module contains the same class names as `collections.abc`, and those were generic since day one.

And, finally, the glory of structural superclasses is that you can define them anytime with [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol). If you can't find a protocol that suits your needs, then just make one. Are you planning to call `__getitem__` but want to support structures that don't have a `len`? Here's your protocol!

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)

class Gettable(Protocol[T]):
    def __getitem__(self, index: int, /) -> T:
        ...
```

Since this class inherits from `Protocol`, when used in type hints it will behave as a structural subtype, meaning any object which has a `__getitem__` that takes an `int` and returns a `T` counts as a `Gettable[T]`, even without an explicit runtime subtyping relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest hinting the parameter as the immutable, but likely equivalent types `tuple` or `frozenset`

```py
def abstract_method(immutable_parameter: tuple | frozenset):
```

Comment: I was not aware of the existance of `frozenset`, thank you!
Whilst calling the function as ```abstract_method(frozenset(mutable_set))``` isn't exactly the most elegant, it is probably not a bad solution